# Join a table witha second 8 times on different foreign keys to fetch same column data from a third table

Tags: sql, oracle, join, oracle-sqldeveloper

I tried searching for this but couldn't find an answer to it. Sorry if there is any answer available. Please direct me and I will read it.

For a real estate company where there are deals which go through different stages where employees verify data and forward it to their superior. In Oracle I have four tables Lets say User, Agent, License, Producer. Now User has detailed information on names and the only connection from user to producer is through Agent and License like this

```
Select * from User u
  inner join Agent a on u.primarykey = a.foreignkey
  inner join License l on a.primarykey = l.foreignkey
  inner join Producer p on l.primarykey = p.foreignkey
```

Now the table producer has 8 different types of Ids based on which position the producer is. For a particular deal there will be different people involved.

I need names of all those people in a single row who are involved in one deal so I have to join the table producer with license 8 times with all the different ids and then fetch the names from entity.

I have doubts on how to fetch the name column which is first name from entity 8 times in the select clause

```
Select entity.first_name,..........
from User u
     inner join Agent a on u.primarykey = a.foreignkey
     inner join License l on a.primarykey = l.foreignkey
     inner join Producer p1 on l.primarykey = p1.foreignkey1
     inner join Producer p2 on l.primarykey = p2.foreignkey2
     inner join Producer p3 on l.primarykey = p3.foreignkey3
     inner join Producer p4 on l.primarykey = p4.foreignkey4
     inner join Producer p5 on l.primarykey = p5.foreignkey5
     inner join Producer p6 on l.primarykey = p6.foreignkey6
     inner join Producer p7 on l.primarykey = p7.foreignkey7
     inner join Producer p8 on l.primarykey = p8.foreignkey8
```

Need to figure out how to write the select clause so that it fetches all the names regarding a particular deal in a single row

Addition of the query I had actually created which was giving results in different rows

```
   with sel as (
    select
     1 key_type
    from dual union all
    select
     2 key_type
    from dual union all
    select
     3 key_type
    from dual union all
    select
     4 key_type
from dual union all
select
 5 key_type
from dual union all
select
6 key_type
from dual union all
select
7 key_type
from dual
)
select
   case
   when pav.key_type = 1 then e.CLIENT_ID
   else NULL 
   end "Column1",
 case
   when pav.key_type = 1  then e.organization_name
   else NULL 
 end "Name 1",
 case
   when pav.key_type = 2 then LTRIM(RTRIM(e.first_name || ' ' || e.middle_name || ' ' || e.last_name))
   else null
 end "Name3",
case
    when pav.key_type = 3 then LTRIM(RTRIM(e.first_name || ' ' || e.middle_name || ' ' || e.last_name))
   else null
end "Name3",
case
   when pav.key_type = 4 then LTRIM(RTRIM(e.first_name || ' ' || e.middle_name || ' ' || e.last_name))
   else null
 end "Name4",
 case
   when pav.key_type = 5 then LTRIM(RTRIM(e.first_name || ' ' || e.middle_name || ' ' || e.last_name))
   else null
 end "Name5",
  case
   when pav.key_type = 6 then LTRIM(RTRIM(e.first_name || ' ' || e.middle_name || ' ' || e.last_name))
   else null
 end "Name6",
  case
   when pav.key_type = 7 then LTRIM(RTRIM(e.first_name || ' ' || e.middle_name || ' ' || e.last_name))
   else null
 end "Name7"
from
 entity e inner join  agent a
 on  e.entity_pk = a.entity_fk
 inner join license al
 on a.agent_pk = al.agent_fk
 inner join (
   select
     case
       when sel.key_type = 1 then pa.producer_agent_license_fk
       when sel.key_type = 2 then coalesce(pa.subproducer_agent_license_fk,pa.producer_agent_license_fk)
       when sel.key_type = 3 then pa.underwriter_license_fk
       when sel.key_type = 4 then pa.policy_serholder_license_fk
       when sel.key_type = 5 then pa.risk_manager_license_fk
       when sel.key_type = 6 then pa.authorizedrep_agent_license_fk
       when sel.key_type = 7 then pa.asst_underwriter_license_fk
     end license_key
   , sel.key_type
   from
     producer pa
   , sel
   where
       pa.effective_end_date = to_date('01/01/3000','mm/dd/yyyy')
 ) pav
on al.license_pk = pav.license_key;
```

Comment: What's the query to fetch them in multiple rows?

Comment: @Kenney: Changes made in the question above

Comment: Thanks. That's awfully complex. Is there a particular reason you need to get them in a single row? It'll be a lot easier if you restructure the `producer` table to store one row for each `*_license_fk`. That way you can simply do a query like `SELECT * FROM Users u JOIN deal d ON d.user_fk = u.pk AND d.effective_end_date = ... WHERE u.pk IS NOT NULL`.

Comment: Sorry, read this 3 times, and still isn't clicking with me what you're looking for.  Could you provide a minimal sample data set along with desired results?

Comment: @Kenney it is a data set provided so cannot make changes in the producer table.